# 12.04/ Firefox and Chrome adobe pdf isnt working

Tags: 12.04, firefox, password, chromium, adobe-reader

When i try to open a pdf in new tab. the browser errors out with a white screen and if i want to open in Document Viewer, i need a password. on my windows machine, it opens just fine. never showing a loading indicator. then i downloaded the .deb of adobe reader from their site and installed it. it fails to open it. on a different 12.04 computer. the adobe reader program opens the pdf but then goes back to grey screen saying "Adobe needs to be updated".

please help.

Answer (score 0):

The Document Viewer usually only asks for a password if the PDF file is encrypted (like an Digital Editons ebook).

Inside Google Chrome (not Chromium) you should be able to see the file using the internal PDF viewer.

Comment: what of firefox?

Comment: Firefox can open PDF files only if the Adobe Reader PDF Plugin is installed. Otherwise it will only try to save/open the file through the application available in the system.